# How do I let a user download multiple files asynchronously in asp.net mvc 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asynchronous

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2.0 & .NET framework 3.5 sp1.

I have an action that currently takes a viewmodel as it's parameter. The action has a return type of FileResult. It's used in my application to generate a pdf and stream it to the user for download. Is there a way to have this action run asynchronously so multiple files can be streamed back to the user? I know this is ugly, but it's what the user requested and b/c privacy & permission issues, these files exist in memory only so I can't zip them together and stream that down. In essence, the user would click what files he wanted to download and a download dialogue would display for each one.

I'm looking into having my controller inherit AsyncController and implementing the MyActionAsync & MyActionCompleted type methods. Based on my own testing, I'm thinking this can't be done. Can someone verify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One request to the server can only return single file. So your code should work just fine as it is - user clicks on a link and get a file, click on another link and gets another file.

If you want to have checkboxes like "file1[], file2[x], file3[x], file4[]" I think you can call click with JavaScript on corresponding links - as long as respons have correct headers it should show file save dialogs. Also user expirience will be strange I think.

Comment: Yea I didn't think this was possible, but the mere idea of trying hadn't occurred to me until a user made the request. The javascript running on each chk box's click event would probably work, but it'd definitely seem wierd.